# htaccess redirect to public and application folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have this directory structure for a MVC project:

```
/
|   .htaccess
|   index.php
+---application
|   +---app
|   |   +---controller
|   |   |       AppController.class.php
|   |   +---files
|   |   |       style.css
|   |   +---model
|   |   \---views
|   |           AllApps.php
|   |           Main.php
|   \---login
|       +---controller
|       |       LoginController.class.php
|       +---files
|       |       application.js
|       |       login.css
|       |       background.png
|       +---model
|       |       LoginModel.class.php
|       \---views
|               Login.php
\---public
    |   .htaccess
    |   index.php
    +---css
    |       bootstrap.css
    +---js
    |       bootstrap.js
    |       jquery.js
```

The htacces file in the root directory contains this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule  (.*)  public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Meanwhile htaccess file in the public folder contains:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$  index.php?url=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [PT,L]   
 </IfModule>
```

What I need is to access the files in each application folder when access is from the following url: mysite.com/__files/login/login.css

I was trying this in the htaccess of the root folder but doesn't work.

```
RewriteRule ^__files/([\d\w]+)/([\d\w]+\.[A-z]{1,4})$    application/$1/files/$2    [L]
RewriteRule  ^((?!__files).)*$  public/$0 [L]
```

Where $1 is the app folder name and $2 is the file name

For testing purpose in index.php file print the $_GET array and always print

```
Array
(
    [url] => application/login/files/application.js
)
```

The strange thing is when I comment the line

```
RewriteRule  ^((?!__files).)*$  public/$0 [L]
```

the access to files in the "files" is correct.

I think after the redirection to file files folder is folder redirection to the public folder, but it shouldn't be.

Comment: htaccess of the root folder

Comment: That's right, in the application folder can be a lot of more "applications" (folders) containing the same directory structure like login and app folders, it's not a static url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that works for myself

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(__files|application) [NC]
RewriteRule  (.*)  public/$1  [L]

RewriteCond $1  ^(__files)*  [NC]
RewriteRule ^__files/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? application/$1/files/$2 [L,NC]
```

The important line is this

> RewriteCond $1 !(__files|application) [NC]

I had tu add ***application*** with ***__files***, it seems that after doing redirect to the application directory it's redirecting to the public folder too.