# Apiplatform with apache

Tags: php, apache, symfony, api-platform.com

I would like to install api-platform on a shared hosting with apache & php.
For development purpose, I simulate this hosting via docker (so I don't want to relie on "docker" installation of apiplatform because this is not the target environment).

I simply created my project with symfony:
`composer create-project symfony/skeleton:"6.1.*" my_project_directory`

I then installed apache-pack:
`composer require symfony/apache-pack`

And finally api-platform:
`composer require api`

When I run `docker-compose up`, Symfony is ready and avalaible at http://localhost/public but api-platform is not. (I tried http://localhost/api and http://localhost/public/api)

I created a repo to let you see: https://github.com/Niolak/api-platform-apache/tree/main/php

Could you help me to make it work please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### After a small research I found this solution:

Enable the `a2enmod` on your `Dockerfile`,

```
// Dockerfile

FROM php:8.1-apache

RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y git

RUN a2enmod rewrite && service apache2 restart
```

Move the `.htaccess` from `public/` to the `src/`. Afterwards rewrite it with:

```
// ./src/.htaccess

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=302]

RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

*P.S: As I mentioned, this was found after a small research. I dont know if it is a good practise or not.*

###### Resources:

1. [.htaccess redirect from site root to public folder, hiding "public" in URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23635746/htaccess-redirect-from-site-root-to-public-folder-hiding-public-in-url)
2. [Redirect all to index.php using htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406156/redirect-all-to-index-php-using-htaccess)
3. [How to enable mod_rewrite for Apache 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2)

Comment: Thanks, it seems all good.